# Python library for a text adventure game

Tags: python, game-development

Looking for recommendations for a Python library that will assist with the development of a simple text adventure game / Interactive Fiction (like Zork, etc.). Python 3 compatibility required.

So far I've found:

- [bwx-adventure](https://github.com/gever/bwx-adventure) which looks promising, but doesn't support Python 3 (although there is a pull request which appears to do that)
- [PAWS](https://github.com/Moonbase59/PAWS), but that also doesn't appear to support Python 3 and seems to have a graphical component because wxPython is a dependency (I'm looking to do text only)

Comment: While I doubt that you will listen to me, I ***strongly*** recommend against this and going with one of the “big two” established i-f programming languages, [Inform](http://inform7.com/) and [TADS](http://www.tads.org/) which have been in development for 15 and 20 years respectively.  Nothing newer is going to be as full featured and bug-free, with such a wide support base. Unless you have ***an  extremely compelling*** reason not to, then you should use one of these. My personal preference is for TDS, but I will admit that Inform has slightly more users.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted)? I used it before for a [Galaga](https://github.com/JustinJmnz/SpaceGame) copy, but It can handle what you are after also. There's a couple of examples of PyGame text based games [here](https://www.pygame.org/tags/textbased). PyGame also supports Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that since you posted this question, bwx-adventure has grown a lot and now supports python3(even though it doesn't look like it in the readme) so you should be good.